# How to add list data to multi sub class list data?

Tags: c#, list, linq, class, subclass

i want add list data from sub class (list) to sub class (list) for sent JSON FORMAT.

**Class**

```
public class MainProcess
{ 
  public Pay _pay { get; set; }
}

public class Pay
{
   public Credit _credit { get; set; }
}

public class Credit 
{
  public int payid { get; set; }
  public List<CreditDetails> details { get; set; }
}

public class CreditDetails
{
  public decimal total { get; set; }
  public List<CreditSubDetails> details { get; set; }
}

public class CreditSubDetails //i want add data to here.
{
  public string runid { get; set; }
  public decimal amount { get; set; }
}
```

**Code C#**

```
private async Task<.....> CreateInfo(Information r)
{
    .....
    ..... //Process Data
    .....

    //Add Data                 
    List<CreditSubDetails> detailsCredit = new List<CreditSubDetails>();
    foreach (var res in resPayDetail.Data.ToList()) //Set data to list
    {
       detailsCredit.Add(new CreditSubDetails()
        {
           runid = res.runid,
           amount = res.totalamount
        });
    }

    var subCreditCardDetails = r._pay._credit.details.SelectMany(x => x.details).ToList();

    //i want add list data to sub class list (class CreditSubDetails)
    //r._pay._credit.details.details = detailsCredit *but not work.

    .....
    .....
    //sent all data (format json)
    response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", r._pay._credit);
    .....
    .....
}
```

Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to add the list `detailsCredit` data to the your `Information r` structure in the path `r._pay._credit.details.details` the only issue as I can see is that you can't access a property of an item through the list of the same item type directly ...

you can't access `details` property of `CreditDetails` class from `List<CreditDetails>` ... you'll need to loop over each item and set `details` for each one.

it should be something like this:

```
r._pay._credit.details.ToList().ForEach(d => {
    d.details = detailsCredit;
});
```